# (BASH) Passing a loop variable into command that will be stored in a variable

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, loops, variables, subshell

I am trying to iterate through a line-by-line list of file ID strings (testIDs.txt) and pass them to an AWS command. The command should utilize the loop variable, and the output of the command should be stored in the "folder" variable. Whenever I run the script, I get blank spaces as output in the terminal.

```
#!bin/bash

while read p; do
    folder=$(aws s3 ls s3://a-bucket/ --recursive | grep "${p}" | cut -c 32-)
    echo "${folder}"
done < testIDs.txt
```

The output of the AWS command should be two strings, and I have checked that this is true by running the AWS line separately in the terminal and using a string instead of `${p}`.

Note: Right now, I simply want to print `folder`, but later I will pass `folder` to another loop.

Comment: Your use of variables looks fine. Are you sure the `aws ... | grep ...  | cut` command is returning what you want?

Comment: Make sure `testIDs.txt` has Unix newlines, not Windows CRLF.

Comment: Try fixing it with `dos2unix testIDs.txt`

Comment: You can also put `set -x` before this to make the shell print each command (or its equivalent) before executing it; this'll make it clearer what's going on (including showing normally-invisible characters like carriage returns).

Comment: @Barmar I think you solved it. Ran dos2unix on my testIDs. The command now echoes what is in "folder". Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar slight issue still there. The file is only echoing one of the lines outputted from the command. Also, the last line in testIDs is being ignored.

Comment: Make sure there's a newline after the last line. `read p` fails if it reads EOF before a newline.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it's only echoing one of the lines, though.

Comment: @Barmar yes I was missing an extra carriage return, thank you. And thanks for your help anyway! Strange because I checked the line in terminal and it definitely outputs two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just use two for loops, (1) read contents of the bucket to temp (optional/could search it directly) , (2) Loop through IDs and (3) loop through each line of the bucket and look for the ID.

Example:

Read the folder structure to local temp, then for every ID look at the line of the file check for the testIDs and print them to a results file.

```
#!bin/bash
TMP="/tmp/s3-log-${RANDOM}.dat"
RESULTS="/tmp/s3-log-results.txt"
ID_FILE="testIDs.txt"

> "${RESULTS}"
aws s3 ls s3://a-bucket/ --recursive > "${TMP}"
while read p; do
    while IFS= read -r line ;do
        if ! [[ $line = *"${p}"* ]]; then
            echo "id: ${p} => $(echo ${line} | cut -c 32-)"  | tee -a "${RESULTS}"
        fi
    done < "${TMP}"        
done < "${ID_FILE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for; use the while loop if you don't know how many values you need to loop through:

```
while read -r -d $'\t' resourceName; do
    echo "$resourceName"
done <<< "$(aws transfer list-servers --query='Servers[*].ServerId' --output text)"
```

In this case it's the `-d $'\t'` that influences the Bash [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) on the list of output AWS resources.